# Simplifying repetitive drawings and node placing

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I use the following code to draw repetitive lines and place nodes in specific locations for later on drawing circles and connecting them with lines.

Is there a simpler way to do this job, as using `\foreach` command or any other possible simpler method.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\hspace {-1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black},dotline/.style={thin, black, loosely dotted}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.6}

\draw [thick,-latex](-.3,0) -- (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3) -- (0,0) -- (0,8);
\draw [thick,-latex](6.,0) -- (7,0) -- (14.4,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](8,-.2) -- (8,0) -- (8,8);
\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*1) node (yal){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {1/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yal.center) node (ya){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {1/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*1) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*2) node (ybl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {2/12}([shift={(0:8)}]ybl.center) node (yb){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {2/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*2) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*3) node (ycl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {3/12}([shift={(0:8)}]ycl.center) node (yc){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {3/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*3) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*4) node (ydl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {4/12}([shift={(0:8)}]ydl.center) node (yd){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {4/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*4) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*5) node (yel){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {5/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yel.center) node (ye){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {5/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*5) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*6) node (yfl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {6/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yfl.center) node (yf){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {6/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*6) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*7) node (ygl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {7/12}([shift={(0:8)}]ygl.center) node (yg){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {7/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*7) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*8) node (yhl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {8/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yhl.center) node (yh){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {8/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*8) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*9) node (yhl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {9/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yhl.center) node (yh){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {9/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*9) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*10) node (yhl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {10/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yhl.center) node (yh){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {10/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*10) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*11) node (yhl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {11/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yhl.center) node (yh){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {11/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*11) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*12) node (yhl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {12/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yhl.center) node (yh){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {12/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*12) -- +(0:14cm);

\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,0) node (al){} +(90:\incrmnt*1) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {1} ([shift={(0:8)}]al.center) node (a){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {1} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*1)}]a.center) node (au){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*1)}]au.center) node (auu){};

\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,0) node (bl){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {2} ([shift={(0:8)}]bl.center) node (b){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {2} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*1)}]b.center) node (bu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]bu.center) node (buu){};

\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,0) node (cl){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {3} ([shift={(0:8)}]cl.center) node (c){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {3} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*3)}]c.center) node (cu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]cu.center) node (cuu){};

\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,0) node (dl){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {4} ([shift={(0:8)}]dl.center) node (d){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {4} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*5)}]d.center) node (du){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]du.center) node (duu){};

\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,0) node (el){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {5} ([shift={(0:8)}]el.center) node (e){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {5} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*7)}]e.center) node (eu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]eu.center) node (euu){};

\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,0) node (fl){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {6} ([shift={(0:8)}]fl.center) node (f){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {6} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*9)}]f.center) node (fu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]fu.center) node (fuu){};

\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,0) node (gl){} +(90:\incrmnt*1) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {7} ([shift={(0:8)}]gl.center) node (g){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {7}([shift={(90:\incrmnt*11)}]g.center) node (gu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*1)}]gu.center) node (guu){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the rest of the code to produce the following drawing

```
    \draw [ultra thick, blue] (au.center) -- (bu.center) (buu.center) -- (cu.center) (cuu.center) -- (du.center) (duu.center) -- (eu.center) (euu.center) -- (fu.center) (fuu.center) -- (gu.center) (guu.center) --+(0:\incrmnt*2) node (inf){};
\draw [thick, black] (inf.center) +(90:\incrmnt*1) --(inf.center|-0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {$\infty$};


\draw [thick, red, fill=red] (au.center) circle (.1) (buu.center) circle (.1) (cuu.center) circle (.1) (duu.center) circle (.1) (euu.center) circle (.1) (fuu.center) circle (.1) (guu.center) circle (.1);

\draw [thick, red, fill=white] (a.center) circle (.14) (bu.center) circle (.14) (cu.center) circle (.14) (du.center) circle (.14) (eu.center) circle (.14) (fu.center) circle (.14) (gu.center) circle (.14);
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this answer I focus on reproducing your output with `\foreach` loops. I do not reproduce your named nodes, which are not used anywhere in your code. One can, of course, produce automatically named nodes, which I can add if they happen to be used.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\hspace {-1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape,
linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black},
dotline/.style={thin, black, loosely dotted}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.6}

\draw [thick,-latex](-.3,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3)  -- (0,8);
\draw [thick,-latex](6.,0)  -- (14.4,0) coordinate (br);
\draw [thick,-latex](8,-.2) -- (8,8) coordinate(tr);
\foreach \X in {1,...,12}
{
\draw [dotline] (0,\X*7cm/12) -- ++ (14,0);
\draw [linecolor] (-\incrmnt/2,\X*7cm/12)node[left]{\X/12} -- ++ (\incrmnt,0)
(8-\incrmnt/2,\X*7cm/12)node[left]{\X/12}-- ++ (\incrmnt,0);
}
\foreach \X in {1,...,7}
{
\draw[linecolor]  (3*\X/5,-\incrmnt/2) node[below]{\X} -- ++ (0,\incrmnt)
(8+3*\X/5,-\incrmnt/2) node[below]{\X} -- ++ (0,\incrmnt);
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tst}{abs(\X-4)}
\ifnum\tst=3
\draw[linecolor]  (3*\X/5,0)  -- ++ (0,7/12)
node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{};
\else
\draw[linecolor]  (3*\X/5,0)  -- ++ (0,14/12)
node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{};
\fi
\ifnum\X=7
\draw[blue,thick]   (8+3*\X/5,{7*(2*\X-2)/12})
node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{} -- ++ (2*7cm/12,0) coordinate(xr);
\else
\draw[blue,thick]  (8+3*\X/5,{7*(2*\X-1)/12}) node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{}
-- ++ (1*7cm/12,0) node[circle,fill=white,draw=red,inner sep=2pt]{};
\fi
}
\draw (tr-|xr) -- (br-|xr) node[below](ir){$\infty$};
\node at (6.5,0 |-ir) {$-\infty$};
\node[circle,fill=white,draw=red,inner sep=2pt,thick] at (8+3/5,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But I need the named nodes, because I use them to complete my drawing by placing lines and circles on the right drawing; which I did not mention to simplify the \foreach command.

Comment: @hany Do you need *nodes* or coordinates? What are the naming conventions? You can name them automatically, even if your naming convention is `a,...,f` using `\alph{X}`, but I'd need to know what the conventions are.

Comment: Please refer to my edited question for the rest of my code. Thank you.

Comment: @Hany If you only want to draw the additional graph, you'll be better off if you do that in the loop as well. (Need to go hibernating now.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. I appreciate them very much.

Comment: @Hany Personally, for reasons of readability of the code and therefore which makes it easy to understand 6 months later, I prefer to make 3 separate loops: one to index the abscissa axis (horizontal), one for the ordinate axis, and one last to draw the graph. It's cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you please tell me how to do it. As you noticed I can not generate code for myself. Do you prefer to post it as a separate question referring to this one.

Comment: Can someone give me a reference on the pgf manual to the `(tr-|xr)` syntax used in the code?

Comment: @Hany I updated my answer

Comment: @AndréC Thank you very much. I appreciate very much your efforts and time.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:**

### Easy-to-read code:

The fundamental principle of programming is to write **easy-to-read** code, especially with a compiled language like TeX. Indeed, the easier the code is to read and understand, the easier it will be to modify in 6 months, 1 year or 10 years...

So, I write (*even if the code is not optimized*) the code per feature block.
Here:

- I first draw the axes of the left graph
- then I draw the graph itself (I put the data in it)
- I do the same with the second graph.

The code thus structured and commented is easy to understand.

### Reuse the code:

The very principle of programming is to **reuse the code**. To do this we can use `macros` or more simply `foreach` loops.

Here you have two graphs with the **same** axes. All you have to do is build it and **reuse it** in a `scope` environment that is moved a few centimetres to the right. This avoids unnecessary calculations.

Once this has been done, the content of the second graph is plotted.

This second graph lends itself well to a `foreach` loop because each time you move `1 unit` to the rigth, you move up `2 units` upwards, hence the formula `\incrmnt*(2*\x-1)` which makes this calculation simple.

The rest is plotted separately since it is not factorizable.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\hspace {-1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black},dotline/.style={thin, black, loosely dotted},
point/.style={circle, draw, red, fill=red, scale=0.4},
cercle/.style={circle,draw,scale=.5, red,thick, fill=white,inner sep=6pt}
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.6}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% plot of the abscissa axis (horizontal) and ordinate axis (on the left)
\draw [thick,-latex](-.3,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3) -- (0,8);

\foreach \y in {1,...,12}{
\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*\y) +(0:.15) -- +(180:.15) node [left] {\y/12};% indexation of ordinate axis (vertical)
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*\y) -- +(0:8*\incrmnt);% horizontal dotted lines
}
\foreach \x in {1,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\x,.15) -- (\incrmnt*\x,-.15) node [below] {\x} ;
    }

% draw of the left graph
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4}]
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,\incrmnt*1) node{} -- (\incrmnt,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,\incrmnt*2) node{}-- (\incrmnt*2,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,\incrmnt*2) node{} -- (\incrmnt*3,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,\incrmnt*2) node{} -- (\incrmnt*4,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,\incrmnt*2) node{} -- (\incrmnt*5,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,\incrmnt*2) node{} -- (\incrmnt*6,.15);
 \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,\incrmnt*1) node {} -- (\incrmnt*7,.15);
\end{scope}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
% graph on the rigth
% plot the same axis by a simple 8cm translation 
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw [thick,-latex](-2,0)node [below right] {$-\infty$}   -- (6,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3)  -- (0,8);
\foreach \y in {1,...,12}{
    \draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*\y) +(0:.15cm) -- +(180:.15cm) node [left] {\y/12};% indexation of ordinate axis (vertical)
    \draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*\y) -- +(0:10*\incrmnt);% horizontal dotted lines
}
\foreach \x in {1,...,7}{
    \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\x,.15) -- (\incrmnt*\x,-.15) node [below] {\x} ;
    }

% draw the graph on the rigth
\draw [thick, black] (\incrmnt*9,0) node [below] {$\infty$} --+(0,\incrmnt*13);
\foreach \x in {1,...,6}{
\draw[ultra thick, blue](\incrmnt*\x,{\incrmnt*(2*\x-1)})node[point]{}--+(\incrmnt,0)node[cercle]{};
}
\node[cercle] at(\incrmnt,0){};
\draw[ultra thick, blue](\incrmnt*7,\incrmnt*12)node[point]{}--+(\incrmnt*2,0);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph-bis]

### Older answer:

To use a `\foreach` loop, it is enough to identify the numbers that are modified in parallel in each line. In your code, the first lines can easily be factorized by a loop.

The following ones are more difficult to factor because there is no regularity that can be easily used.

Edit: correction of an omission of factorization

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{}
    \hspace {-1cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black},dotline/.style={thin, black, loosely dotted}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.6}

    \draw [thick,-latex](-.3,0) -- (0,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3) -- (0,0) -- (0,8);
    \draw [thick,-latex](6.,0) -- (7,0) -- (14.4,0);
    \draw [thick,-latex](8,-.2) -- (8,0) -- (8,8);

% Factoring the first 12 operations `\draw`:
    \foreach \y in {1,...,12}{
    \draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*\y) node (yhl){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {\y/12}([shift={(0:8)}]yhl.center) node (yh){} +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.8cm, yshift=0cm] {\y/12};
    \draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*\y) -- +(0:14cm);
    }

    \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,0) node (al){} +(90:\incrmnt*1) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {1} ([shift={(0:8)}]al.center) node (a){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {1} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*1)}]a.center) node (au){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*1)}]au.center) node (auu){};

    \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,0) node (bl){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {2} ([shift={(0:8)}]bl.center) node (b){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {2} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*1)}]b.center) node (bu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]bu.center) node (buu){};

    \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,0) node (cl){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {3} ([shift={(0:8)}]cl.center) node (c){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {3} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*3)}]c.center) node (cu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]cu.center) node (cuu){};

    \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,0) node (dl){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {4} ([shift={(0:8)}]dl.center) node (d){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {4} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*5)}]d.center) node (du){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]du.center) node (duu){};

    \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,0) node (el){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {5} ([shift={(0:8)}]el.center) node (e){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {5} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*7)}]e.center) node (eu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]eu.center) node (euu){};

    \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,0) node (fl){} +(90:\incrmnt*2) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {6} ([shift={(0:8)}]fl.center) node (f){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {6} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*9)}]f.center) node (fu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*2)}]fu.center) node (fuu){};

    \draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,0) node (gl){} +(90:\incrmnt*1) node [circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4]{} -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {7} ([shift={(0:8)}]gl.center) node (g){} +(90:.25cm) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {7}([shift={(90:\incrmnt*11)}]g.center) node (gu){} ([shift={(90:\incrmnt*1)}]gu.center) node (guu){};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image: graphs]

Comment: Thank you very much. If you ignore the different lengths and circles of the left drawing and make them equal (without circles) as in the right drawing; then draw the different length lines later on; could this simplify using \foreach command to automate the repetition?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and time. I will follow with marmot the rest of my code.