# Multiplying a number defined in a style

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, how can I display the result of a style-defined number multiplication, to show 50 instead of 25*2, and so on.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1., transform shape,linecolor/.style={thick, blue}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{25}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,6);
\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*1) +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.68cm, yshift=0cm] {2};
\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*2) +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.68cm, yshift=0cm] {4};
\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*3) +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.68cm, yshift=0cm] {6};
\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*4) +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.68cm, yshift=0cm] {8};
\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*5) +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.68cm, yshift=0cm] {10};

\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {\inc*1};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {\inc*2};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {\inc*3};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {\inc*4};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {\inc*5};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {\inc*6};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {\inc*7};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\pgfmathsetmacro\number{\inc*\x}` and then `\pgfmathprintnumber\number` in a `foreach loop` (for example: `\pgfmathsetmacro\test{2*5}` and then `\pgfmathprintnumber\test`) …

Comment: @current_user Thank you for your comment. Would you please tell me how to use it. I could not apply your idea. I did not use foreach loop in my question. Just apply it in one of my lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To place labels, there are `left`, `rigth`, `below`, `above` keys that place the text on the left, right, below and above the **last plotted point**. 
Thus, it is enough to draw the point where you want to place a label **last** and not to draw it first which complicates the placement of labels.

For the y-axis, write simply:

```
\draw [linecolor] (.15,\incrmnt*1) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {2};
```

instead of:

```
\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*1) +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.68cm, yshift=0cm] {2};
```

Similarly for the abscissa axis, simply write:

```
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:\incrmnt+.25) node [below] {\inc*1};
```

instead of

```
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=-.35cm] {\inc*1};
```

You will get this :

```
\draw [linecolor] (.15,\incrmnt*1) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {2};
\draw [linecolor] (.15,\incrmnt*2) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {4};
\draw [linecolor] (.15,\incrmnt*3) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {6};
\draw [linecolor] (.15,\incrmnt*4) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {8};
\draw [linecolor] (.15,\incrmnt*5) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {10};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:\incrmnt+.25) node [below] {\inc*1};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:\incrmnt+.25) node [below]{\inc*2};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:\incrmnt+.25) node [below] {\inc*3};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:\incrmnt+.25) node [below] {\inc*4};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:\incrmnt+.25) node [below] {\inc*5};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:\incrmnt+.25) node [below] {\inc*6};
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:\incrmnt+.25) node [below]{\inc*7};
```

This significantly reduces the code and makes it easier to understand.

Now you notice that your code is repeating itself, so it is easier to use two foreach loops.
The syntax of foreach loops allows calculations to be performed according to a particular syntax starting with `[evaluate=...]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1., transform shape,linecolor/.style={thick, blue}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{25}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,6);
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*2)]in {1,...,5}{
\draw [linecolor] (.15,\incrmnt*\y) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {\aff};
}

\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\inc*\x)]in {1,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\x,.15) -- +(-90:.3) node [below] {\aff};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: graphs]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. But this is an MWE, not the whole drawing. I want to concentrate only in displaying the result of a style-defined number multiplication, to show 50 instead of 25*2, and so on. Please ignore using \foreach, because the lines are irrelevant, they do not have equal length.

Comment: @Hany I have already explained here that your way of constructing graphs is too complicated. You must first build the two axes and then place its content. Please consider here that I have drawn the two axes. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457160/138900

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please ignore my graph, concentrate only in displaying the result of a style-defined number multiplication, to show 50 instead of 25*2, and so on.

Comment: @Hany If your lines do not have equal length, just draw them outside the `\foreach`, and use the `\foreach` only for the axis ticks

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you. Please ignore my graph, and concentrate only in displaying the result of a style-defined number multiplication, to show 50 instead of 25*2, and so on.

Comment: @Hany CarlaTeX and I answered this question by placing the labels on the axes with a foreach. Otherwise, to make calculations, you must use `\pgfmathsetmacro`

Comment: @AndréC Thank you. I will follow your comments. Please tell me how to use \pgfmathsetmacro for calculations.

Comment: @Hany Complete your question with your complete graph so that we can explain it to you.

Comment: @AndréC Please ignore my graph and just tell me how to use \pgfmathsetmacro for calculations for displaying the result, to show 50 instead of 25*2, and so .

Comment: @Hany Look at examples of usage in the following questions and answers, it will help you even more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cpgfmathsetmacro

Comment: @AndréC Thank you very much for your answer and comments. I will follow them.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you very much for your answer and comments. I will follow them.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with two simple `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[linecolor/.style={thick, blue}]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,6);
\foreach[evaluate=\myy as \myylab using int(\myy*2)] \myy in {1,2,...,5}{
\draw [linecolor] (0,\myy) +(180:.15cm) -- +(0:.15cm) node [xshift=-.68cm] {\myylab};}

\foreach[evaluate=\myx as \myxlab using int(\myx*25)] \myx in {1,2,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\myx,0) +(90:1) -- +(-90:.25cm) node [yshift=-.35cm] {\myxlab};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I want only to display the result of the multiplication of \inc, without affecting other components as the length of the lines. This is an MWE not the whole drawing.

Comment: @Hany Sorry, a typo, I'll correct immediately

Comment: @Hany See my renewed answer